# Uncaught (in promise) Error: InvalidStateError: While connecting my React client to Spring websocket server

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs

While trying to connect my React client to Spring boot web socket server. I am getting this error while socket connection, but seems like the messages are sent. I am completely clueless what's happening here and could some one please explain and suggest a solution.

```
        configureSocket = async (channel_id) => {
        var socket = new socketClient(SERVER+'/chat')
        var stompClient = stompjs.over(socket)
        stompClient.connect({}, (frame)=>{
            console.log("Connected to: "+frame)
            stompClient.subscribe("/chat/messages/"+channel_id, (response) => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.body)
                console.log(data)
            } )
        })
        this.socket = socket
        this.stompClient = stompClient
        
    }

    handleSendMessage = async (channel_id, text, from) => {
        await this.configureSocket(channel_id);
        this.stompClient.send("/app/chat/"+channel_id, {}, await JSON.stringify({
            'from': from, 
            'message': text
            }))
        }
```

[image: Reference image of the browser]